# What kind of response should I return from a simple django AJAX view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am inexperienced with AJAX, but pretty comfortable with Django. I am trying to write a simple search page that uses jQuery to fetch matching results and inserts them into the page using jQuery load, like this:

```
 $("#results").load(targetURL)
```

Without using AJAX, I would format the results queryset returned from the view using template iteration. With AJAX, I can't use the template to format the results.  My current solution is to format results as HTML in the view, and return this HTML from the AJAX view, which is then loaded by jQuery.

```
### AJAX View
def myview(request):
    matches = model.objects.filter(type__exact="thisType")
    results_html = ""
    for each in matches:
        results_html += "<tr><td> each.name </td></tr>"
    return HttpResponse(results_html)
```

#### This seems a hacky to me! Is there a better way?

Should I be returning a json dump of the queryset?  If so, any tips on how to process/format this returning json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you respond with a json dump, then you can process it in js like this:

```
$.get(targetURL).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(i,d) {
    $("#results").append($("<tr><td>" + d.name + "</td></tr>"));
  });
});
```

Or like this:

```
$.get(targetURL).done(function(data) {
  $("#results").append(data.map(function(i,d) {
    return $("<tr><td>" + d.name + "</td></tr>");
  }));
});
```

Comment: OK this makes sense.  And I probably get performance gains this way too, because the client is doing some of the work, right?

Comment: Performance gains would be minimal unless you're serving google-sized traffic.

Comment: Interesting, Joe....so would you say that returning HTML straight from the view is a viable solution?

Comment: Depends on your use-case. Both ways are viable. If you plan on doing any further manipulation (e.g. sorting the list, or calculating averages, histograms, etc), then send json. If the browser will only ever expect html, and you want to keep the client-side js to a minimum, then send html.